Issue writing a large file to databricks table
I'm having difficulties writing a very large file (over 12 million rows of data) to databricks.
from pyspark.sql import Row
testDF = spark.read.csv(path='path', schema=generic_struct, sep='|', header='false')

current_to = None
part_rows = []
prt_seq = 0
 
for idx, row in enumerate(testDF.rdd.toLocalIterator()):

    if row['RECORD_TYPE'] == '03':
        #convert Row object to dictionary to make it mutable and assign TO value.
        rowDict = row.asDict()
        prt_seq += 1
        rowDict['TO_NUM'] = current_to
        rowDict['PRT_SEQ'] = prt_seq
        # Create new row object using kwargs unpacking and add it to the list
        part_rows.append(Row(**rowDict))


partDF = spark.createDataFrame(part_rows, generic_struct).selectExpr(list of column headers)

missingPartDF = spark.sql("""
    Irrelevant SQL
"""
)

partDF = partDF.union(missingPartDF)

partDF.write.csv('path/database/table', header=True, sep =',', escape="\"", mode='overwrite')


When I try to run the above code, I get the following error:
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 194614:0 was 1155776614 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.rpc.message.maxSize (268435456 bytes). Consider increasing spark.rpc.message.maxSize or using broadcast variables for large values.

As a result, I tried to chunk the dictionary out before writing it to the table with the following, but the script keeps timing out:
from itertools import islice

def chunks(data, SIZE=1000000):
  it = iter(data)
  for i in range(0, len(data), SIZE):
     yield {k:data[k] for k in islice(it, SIZE)}       

Is there a more efficient way to handle a file of this size?

Can you add what is your input csv and your expected schema of your output csv?
